# GuzzleHTTP headers not set properly

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm trying to send a GET request to an api with my keys. My keys need to be in the header. I have saved my keys in an array `$api` and given them to Guzzle.

When I send the GET request I get a `403 Forbidden` response, my best guess is that the headers aren't actually being set.

```php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$api = array(
    "X-Api-Id" => "id",
    "X-Api-Secret" => "secret",
    "X-Api-Key" => "key"
);

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    "base_uri" => "example.com",
    "timeout" => 5
]);

$response = $this->client->request("GET", "/configs/", ["verify" => false, "headers" => $api]);
var_dump($response);
```

The error

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://api.onetap.com/configs/` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:     <!--[if IE 7]> <html class (truncated...) in C:\scaryconfigscc\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113

Comment: guzzle docs don't show request method as something that exists, but the issue seems to be the headers aren't being added, can you check that the headeras has to be within the third parameter of the request method? which guzzle version are you using?

Comment: Tried this way `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']]);` and after send the request `$this->client->request("GET", "/configs/");`?

Comment: @GaimZz I just installed it via composer so I'm guessing the latest, not sure how to check. am a bit new to PHP

Comment: @gaidyjg results in the same for me

Comment: Why can't you just tell what API you're talking about?

Comment: As it doesn't matter, you need to have a paid account to use it & read the documentation. Hence I try to explain.

Comment: You can use a man in the middle proxy like fiddler to see what headers, request and responses are being sent.

Comment: Can you check that your ip is not getting blocked due to security firewalls?

Comment: Also try to add these additional headers:
'User-Agent' => 'YOUR TOOL NAME v1.0',
 'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',

Comment: "my best guess is that the headers aren't actually being set" What seems more likely: this widely used (> 250m installs) mature (> 10 years old) HTTP client library is fundamentally broken, or that the server doesn't like your credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers) doesn't show it much different, besides it also has default headers:

```
try {
    $response = $client->request('GET', '/configs', [
        'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
            'Accept'     => 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Id' => 'id',
            'X-Api-Secret' => 'secret',
            'X-Api-Key' => 'key'
        ]
    ]);
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

If it doesn't work - either the credentials are wrong or it may possibly expect method POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Use `$request->getHeader()` to retrieve all the headers that are being sent and check if the required headers are set.
2. Check `$response->getHeader()` and verify is the api is looking to set a cookie. In case a cookie is actually being set, you will need to set a cookiejar (https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies).

If both the above does not solve the problem then things get complicated. It is more of trial and error from here on. You can try one or all of the following:

- Change user agent
- it could be that the api is blocking your IP (so you need to try it on a different server or IP)
- they could be detecting some of your use as an offending user and may be blocking the request via their firewall or at the app level. What triggers the rules is for you and them to figure out.

If it still does not work you will need to contact their support or share more details before anyone can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I you receive a http response `403 Forbidden` then you either not allowed to communicate with the url you request (check if you have all api keys etc generated) and/or your request is incomplete/wrong.

You may exclude Guzzle as a reason of the failure and narrow the possible causes by doing the same request with other tools. If you succeed then it means the problem is with the Guzzle, but if you don't then one of the problems described above is the real issue.

To do request with PHP's native funcion [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) use this code:

```
<?php

# display as a plain text instead of html, just for test
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

# full url including '/configs'
$url = 'https://www.example.com/configs/';

$headers = [
    "X-Api-Id" => "id",
    "X-Api-Secret" => "secret",
    "X-Api-Key" => "key"
];

# optional query str
// $queryArr = [
//    'key' => 'value'
// ];

# ----------- prepare request -----------------
if (!empty($queryArr)) {
    $url .= '?' . http_build_query($queryArr);
}

$opts = [];
$opts['http']['method'] = "GET";
if (!empty($headers)) {
    $headersStr = '';
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        $headersStr .= $header . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
    }
    $opts['http']['header'] = $headersStr;
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
}
# ----------- prepare request end ------------

if (isset($context)) {
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
} else {
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
}
echo $response;
```

I checked that method with my own service and it works, all headers are send.

But if you don't believe me you can do the same by using [cURL](https://curl.se/windows/).
Type in the command line:

```
curl --insecure -L -H -S -v --connect-timeout 5 -H "X-Api-Id: id" -H "X-Api-Secret: secret" -H "X-Api-Key: key" "https://www.example.com/configs/"
```

you may need instead of `curl` at the beginning use the full path to the executable like `C:\Downloads\curl.exe` at Windows.

The options I used:

```
--insecure      Allow insecure server connections when using SSL
-L, --location      Follow redirects
-H, --header <header/@file> Pass custom header(s) to server
-S, --show-error    Show error even when -s is used
-v A line  starting  with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data"
   received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting  with  '*'  means  additional
   info provided by curl.
--connect-timeout <seconds> Maximum time allowed for connection
```

You should firstly try the command line above without:

```
--insecure      Allow insecure server connections when using SSL
```

but if you have a problem on Windows with checking certificates this is one of the workarounds (not recommended), it is better to fix that problem

for the command line curl certificate [check this link](https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html), see section Certificate Verification point 4.
Additionally [how to fix certificate problem with php](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-curl-ssl-certificate-error/)

If you run the command line curl example as above you should get something like that in the output:

```
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET /configs/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Api-Id: id
> X-Api-Secret: secret
> X-Api-Key: key
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

(...)
```

where as previously mentioned:

```
-v A line  starting  with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data"
```

So you can be sure and have a proof that the headers were send:

```
> X-Api-Id: id
> X-Api-Secret: secret
> X-Api-Key: key
```

There are some additional headers like:

```
> Accept: */*
```

And if you want to receive a response body as `json` you probably should also set this header too by adding to the command line:

```
-H "Accept: application/json"
```

but check that with the documentation of the api you request.

Once you confirm everything is working as it should by `file_get_contents` or `cURL` command line you can check everything with the `Guzzle`. Before you do that check if your php has `curl` by the command line:

```
php -m
```

you will see all the extensions in the php installed and there should be an extension named `curl`

Guzzle example to do a request with headers and optional query string.
I used guzzle installed by this command:

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.2"
```

Code using Guzzle:

```
<?php

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

# display as a plain text instead of html, just for test
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;

try {

    $headers = [
        "X-Api-Id" => "id",
        "X-Api-Secret" => "secret",
        "X-Api-Key" => "key"
    ];

    # optional query str
    // $queryArr = [
    //    'key' => 'value'
    // ];

    $method = 'GET';
    $scheme = 'https';
    $baseUrl = 'www.example.com';
    $urlDir = '/configs/';
    $baseUri = strtolower($scheme) . '://' . $baseUrl;

    $clientConfigArr = [
        'base_uri' => $baseUri,
        RequestOptions::TIMEOUT => 5.0, // Timeout if a server does not return a response in 5 seconds.
        RequestOptions::VERIFY => false, // Disable validation entirely (don't do this!).
        RequestOptions::DEBUG => true,
    ];

    # set method to default value if not set
    if (empty(trim($method))) {
        $method = 'GET';
    }

    # set location to / if not set
    if (empty(trim($urlDir))) {
        $urlDir = '/';
    }

    # add query string if query arr not empty
    if (!empty($queryArr)) {
        $urlDir .= '?' . http_build_query($queryArr);
    }

    # if headers are set
    if (!empty($headers)) {
        # create request with headers
        $request = new Request(strtoupper(trim($method)), $urlDir, $headers);
    } else {
        # create request without headers
        $request = new Request(strtoupper(trim($method)), $urlDir);
    }

    # create client and send a the requrest
    $client = new Client($clientConfigArr);
    $response = $client->sendRequest($request);

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\TransferException $e) {
        
    $msg = ' ';
    $msg .= \PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= '[BAD] [Transfer ERR: ' . $e->getCode() . ']' . \PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= 'at ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . \PHP_EOL;
    if (!empty($response) && is_object($response) && method_exists($response, 'getBody')) {
        $msg .= '[Response Body] ' . (string) $response->getBody() . \PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "$msg";
    exit(1);

} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    $msg = '';
    $msg .= \PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= '[BAD] [ERROR Throwable]' . \PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= '[Message] ' . $e->getMessage() . \PHP_EOL;
    $msg .= 'at ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "$msg";
    exit(1);
}

echo '[OK] [SUCCESS]' . \PHP_EOL . \PHP_EOL;
echo $response->getBody() . \PHP_EOL;
```

Note that using:

```
RequestOptions::VERIFY => false
```

is the same as using `--insecure` for cURL command line and should be avoided, better fix the problem with the SSL certificates by following the instruction previously given. Having that problem fixed you may remove the `RequestOptions::VERIFY => false` from the `$clientConfigArr`

Guzzle usefull links:
[Request](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#guzzle-and-psr-7)
[Request Options](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html)
[How to check if a request or response has a specific header.](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#accessing-headers)
[Client](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-a-client)
[Response](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#responses)
[Exceptions](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=transferexception#exceptions)

It is possible that you should not do the `GET` request but `POST` instead as Martin mentioned. If you want to make a request with different method then:

[Request Methods](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html?highlight=post#request-methods)

For the `POST` method you will need most likely send a body as well, you can create a `POST` `Request` and attach the body this way:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$headers = ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'];
$body = 'hello!';
$request = new Request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', $headers, $body);

# and send request (as in the Guzzle example)
$client = new Client($clientConfigArr);
$response = $client->sendRequest($request);
```

check with the api documentation if you need to pass some body content (perhaps your token) if you are going to do the `POST` request (or any other method)

A side note:
In the Guzzle Code example instead of [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) I used [require_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) because:

> if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again.

[source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Therefore you can use in may files as many times as you want:

```
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
```

and everything will work fine, in contrary to the `require` without `once` that will very often make you duplicate declaration errors.

For having windows like backslashes you may use [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) and [**DIR**](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.constants.predefined.php) as a current dir. Using them both like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';
```

Just in case you would like to know.